# Issuing commands to the command line in Python

Tags: python, django, apache, command

This is my code. I'm pretty new to this.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["cd", "/etc/apache2/"])
```

However, when this function is run, I get

```
Errno 2: No such file or directory
```

I am running Django within Apache*. This is my views.py file. Ask for additional code, and you shall receive.

edit - It should be noted that `/etc/apache2/` does indeed exist.

Comment: please describe what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: I'm trying to issue a command to the command line, namely the cd folderpath command. I'm beginning to suspect that this is not the way!

Comment: it definitely is not as it will have no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the working directory of the Python process you can use `chdir` from the `os` module:

```
import os

os.chdir('/etc/apache2')
```

Comment: This is better, thank you. However, I need to write this to command line as I'm modifying the htpsswd file in Apache with a new user that is being registered.

I will use this in another clause, though, which does not rely on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will not get what you expect if you run this. Try

```
import os
os.chdir('/etc/apache2')
```

Second, try `/path/to/cd` as process may not know `cd` alias.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to issue commands to the command line itself. The working directory of Python is not what I need.